# how to make an xml http post request from the information provided by the google chrome inspector

Tags: python, python-requests

**This question is no duplicate, as adding user-agent to a header isn't fixing anything.**

I've been trying to get the response from this [URL](https://www.cashpoint.dk/index.php?r=games/oddsupdate). It's an XML feed, not an HTML file. It's a live feed updated every second from cashpoint.com's [live soccer page](https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/live/index.html). I can just fine get the HTML page from the last-mentioned page, but from the first mentioned URL I can't retrieve the XML data. I can inspect it with google chrome inspector and see the response just fine. But it returns b''. Tried both get and post.

**EDIT:** Tried to add some more headers but it still doesn't work.

Shouldn't it be possible it retrieve this information if the inspector can see it?

Below is my code and some pictures (if you are too busy to check the links).

```
import requests

class GetFeed():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def live_odds(self):

        live_index_page = 'https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/live/index.html'
        live_oddsupdate = 'https://www.cashpoint.dk/index.php?r=games/oddsupdate'

        r = requests.get(live_oddsupdate)

        print(r.text)

feed = GetFeed()
feed.live_odds()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: what data do you want? even if you change it to a post request it will give you the html page. Is that what you want?

Comment: you're also going to want to print r.content() not r.text()

Comment: Not a duplicate, doesn't work to enter user-agent as a header.

Comment: kay, I can retrieve the html page just fine. The html page doesn't contain the live feed and isn't updated every second.

Comment: You're doing a bunch of things different from the browser request. GET instead of POST is only the first difference. There may be cookies you need. Or different headers—and not just User-Agent; some sites switch on Referer, or maybe you need to tell it that you accept JSON rather than HTML content, or…

Comment: I thought it was possible to replicate what google chrome inspector shows in the response somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some data and some headers in a post request. Try this:

```
url = 'https://www.cashpoint.dk/index.php?r=games/oddsupdate'

headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.517291307.1531264976; _gid=GA1.2.1421702183.1531264976; _pk_id.155.9810=7984b0a0e139caba.1531264979.1.1531264979.1531264979.; cookieConsent=1; cpLanguage=en; langid=2; ad_network=DIRECT; PHPSESSID=f4mbbfd8adb3m59gfc1pelo126"
}

data = "parameters%5Baction%5D=odds_update&parameters%5Bgame_category%5D=live&parameters%5Bsport_id%5D=&parameters%5Btimestamp%5D=1531268162&parameters%5Bgameids%5D=%5B905814%2C905813%2C905815%2C905818%2C905792%5D&formToken=c3fed3ea6b46dae171a6f1a6d21db14fcc21474c"

response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

print response.content
```

Just tested this and it works. The point here is that ALL of this information can be found on the exact same xhr network inspection in google chrome. Next time, please read up on xmlhttprequests before you post a question.

Comment: Kay thank you so much!!!!!! 

I had to add the data to my post request

I'll read up on xmlhttprequests and I'll try study requests api some more!

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one, in the Chrome console you can see that it's a POST request, and it appears you're performing a GET request in your Python code.

Comment: So how do I retrieve the data? I'm sorry, kinda new to python and requests. I tried to do requests.post() which didn't give me the data output

Comment: @jubibanna "I tried to do `requests.post()` isn't something anyone can debug. You have to show us the code you tried, and what happened. (If I try your exact same code, just changing `get` to `post`, I get back a 600K HTML error page, not nothing.)

Comment: b''
>>> is what a get when using "get", I get the html doc page when using post. The oddsupdate url doesn't contain the html doc, the index.html page contains this. I tried to show it in the screenshots.  Sorry if it isnt clear

Comment: @jubibanna Looks like you get some XML back from the oddsupdate request. Maybe try parsing that as your next step.

Comment: Exactly! I am trying to get that XML back, but how do I get that ? Tried to add 'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01', to my header and now I get this: "b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">\n<html><head>\n<title>503 Service Unavailable</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Service Unavailable</h1>\n<p>The server is temporarily unable to service your\nrequest due to maintenance downtime or capacity\nproblems. Please try again later.</p>\n</body></html>\n'
>>> "

Comment: @jubibanna You may be missing more than just accept headers. Try duplicating the request that you see in the Chrome console as closely as possible. You may be missing some sort of origin or authentication or session or other weird headers.

Comment: Or you may be rate limited

Comment: Okay, Hatchet, I'll try edit the small things and try run it from a vpn as well at some point. I'll be carefull not spamming request. 
I should use post, right? Not get?

Comment: Use what works. It appears to me that in this case using a POST request would be the correct thing to do. Please make another question if you have more issues.